# google-analytics Event Tracking referral path Previous History

Tags: php, google-analytics, browser-history, event-tracking, referrals

I am looking in using the EVENT TRACKING with **Google Analytics**. Everything is working great so far.

Code:

```
<input OnClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Submit Application', 'Apply', '<?php echo "$actual_link" ?>');" type="submit" class="wpjb-submit" id="wpjb_submit" value="<?php _e("Send Application", "wpjobboard") ?>" />

ga('send', 'event', 'Submit Application', 'Apply', '<?php echo "$actual_link" ?>');"
```

What I want to do is the Submit Application to be a Referral Path. How did they get to this button basically the previous history whether its from my site or another link. I have job postings on Linkedin and Indeed so it would be great if someone clicked on the link in either of these sites then they get redirected to the job where they can apply which this button is located.

Is there anyway I can get the data from where they came from for EVENT TRACKING?

Comment: You can use javascript `document.referrer;` variable to check where people came from.